# how can i change language parameter url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Currently my urls links are displaying this way

```
/news?lang=en
```

how can i make RewriteRule to display URLS like this

```
/news/en
```

This is what i've tried so far

```
RewriteRule ^?lang=(.*) /$1 [QSA]
```

I'm no really understanding .htaccess till the end how it exactly works

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that his is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?news/(en|de|fr|es)/?$ /news?lang=$1 [END]
```

In case that rule results in an "internal server error" (http status 500), then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case either update your server or try using the older `[L]` flag instead of the `[END]` flag. It *might* work the same, but that depends on the rest of the setup. You will find a clear hint on the `[END]` flag not being supported in that case in your http servers error log file.

That rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file). If you really have to use such a dynamic file then take care that it's interpretation is enabled in your host configuration and that above rule is placed in such a file inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of the http host.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).